# How does this Clojure function expand?

Tags: clojure

From The Joy of Clojure :

```
(defn fac-cps [n k]
  (letfn [(cont [v] (k (* v n)))]
   (if (zero? n)
    (k 1)
   (recur (dec n) cont))))

(defn fac [n]
  (fac-cps n identity))

(fac 10)
3628800
```

I am interested to learn how the above function expands.

`fac-cps` is called with `10` and `identity`...

but in letfn `cont[v]` is defined as `(k (* v n))`

which equates to `k` = `identity`, `n` = `10`

But i don't understand what `v` equates to and what `recur` expands into.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers.  I now understand how **cont** is used along with recur.  But I do have a followup question.  Why do we need to use **identify** ?  This is something I'm still not clear about.  Any explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: Because `fac-cps` wants a function, and `identity` is harmless ([identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of function composition). For a parallel example, how do you normally sum an array? Typically, you'd start with 0, then add the first element, then add the second element... Why start with 0, if it's not in the array? Because it's harmless (identity element of addition).

Comment: Got it..didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the lines are the same. I've just used substitution rules:

```
(fac-cps 10 identity)
(recur 9 (fn [v] (identity (* v 10))))
(recur 8 (fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))))
(recur 7 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8)))) 
(recur 6 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))))  
(recur 5 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))))  
(recur 4 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))))  
(recur 3 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))))
(recur 2 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))) (* v 3))))
(recur 1 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))) (* v 3))) (* v 2))))
(recur 0 (fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))) (* v 3))) (* v 2))) (* v 1))))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))) (* v 3))) (* v 2))) (* v 1))) 1)
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))) (* v 3))) (* v 2))) (* 1 1))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))) (* v 3))) (* (* 1 1) 2))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (* v 4))) (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* v 5))) (*  (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3) 4))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* v 6))) (* (* (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3) 4) 5))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* v 7))) (* (* (* (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) 6))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* v 8))) (* (* (* (* (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) 6) 7))
((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* v 9))) (* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) 6) 7) 8))
((fn [v] (identity (* v 10))) (* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) 6) 7) 8) 9))
(identity (* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* (* 1 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) 6) 7) 8) 9) 10))
(identity 3628800)
; ==> 3628800
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the type in all the expansions.  That really helped understand the way the functions are called and expanded.  Cheers

Comment: That qualifies as ascii art

Answer (score 0):

On the first call to `fac-cps`, `k` is the `identity` function. The `letfn` form immediately creates a new function that takes an argument `v`, and captures `k` (`identity`) in a closure.

Then it checks if `n` is zero, which is the base/terminal case for this recursion.

Otherwise, there's more work to do, so it recurs while decrementing `n`, but now passing the new `cont` function that closed over `k`. This will happen over and over until `n` reaches zero, creating a blooming onion of nested closures. This is called *continuation passing style* and that's what the `cps` in `fac-cps` stands for. Contrast this with a purely recursive approach where those values that were captured in closures would instead be on the call stack.

Note that the *work* in `cont` (in all of them, nested in each other) isn't done until the very end when `n` reaches zero. When `k` is invoked in the terminal case, it's a function that may be wrapping many other functions. In other words, this is building up a thunk to be evaluated at the end. For example, `(fac-cps 3)` would end up evaluating this function:

```
(fn [v] ((fn [v] ((fn [v] (identity (* v 3))) (* v 2))) (* v 1)))
```

> but i don't understand what v equates to

`v` is an argument to `cont`, so it won't be known until `cont` is invoked.

> what recur expands into

`recur` is a special form that re-enters the function "recursively" but without consuming stack. You could replace `recur` with `fac-cps`, but you'd get a stack overflow if `n` is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

This function evaluates factorial by building up a continuation (basically a function that will do the work in the future), then evaluating it at `(fac-cps 0)`.

E.g. at `(fac-cps 3)`, continuation is "take a number, multiply it with 3, then pass it to the previous continuation, which will leave it alone (`identity`)".

At `(fac-cps 2)`, continuation is "take a number, multiply it with 2, then pass it to the previous continuation, which will multiply it by 2 and pass it to the previous continuation, which will leave it alone".

At `(fac-cps 1)`, continuation is "take a number, multiply it with 1, then pass it to the previous continuation, which will multiply it by 2 and pass it to the previous continuation, which will multiply it by 3 and pass it to the previous continuation, which will leave it alone."

Then finally, at `(fac-cps 0)`, the number is given: `1 * 3 * 2 * 1` is the result.